# Is it possible to see what commands a program is executing?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, process-explorer

I have a Windows GUI program, that upon startup, launches cmd.exe and I would like to know exactly what commands are executed within the command shell.  I know cmd.exe is executed as soon as the program is started as ZoneAlarm asks me whether to allow it to run or not.  I've tried Process Explorer but I don't think it has what I need.

Many thanks for your insights.

Comment: Try Process Monitor instead of Process Explorer.  It literally captures everything happening, but you'll have to narrow down using filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the command line that was used to start a process quite simply.

Go to `View` -> `Select Columns`.  In the `Process Image` tab, check `Command Line`.

Now, you should be able to see the full path to the process and whatever command line arguments were used.

---

It's worth noting that the regular task manager has this ability too (but somewhat limited for some processes).

In the `Processes` tab, go to `View` -> `Select Columns` and check `Command Line` (look familiar?).

You should find that most processes that you probably would care about will have the command lines shown in a similar manner.